# Regex and shell - multiple recursive rename

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I have a folder with several hundreds of folders inside it. These folders contain another folder each, called images, and in this folder there is sometimes a strictly numerically named .jpg file. Sometimes there are other JPG files in the folder as well, but these need to be ignored if they aren't strictly numeric.

I would like to learn how to write a script which would, when run in a given folder, traverse every single subfolder and look for this numeric file. It would then add the "_n" suffix to a **copy** of each, if such a file does not already exist.

Can this be done through the unix terminal easily?

To be more specific, this is the structure I'm dealing with:

- master folder

  - 18556

    - images

      - 2234.jpg
  - 47772

    - images

      - 2234.jpg
      - 2234_n.jpg
      - some_pic.jpg
  - 77377

    - images
  - 88723

    - images

      - 22.jpg
      - some_pic.jpg

After the script is run, the situation would look like this:

- master folder

  - 18556

    - images

      - 2234.jpg
      - 2234_n.jpg
  - 47772

    - images

      - 2234.jpg
      - 2234_n.jpg
      - some_pic.jpg
  - 77377

    - images
  - 88723

    - images

      - 22.jpg
      - 22_n.jpg
      - some_pic.jpg

Update: Sorry about the typo, I accidentally put 2235 into 47772.
Update 2: Regarding the 2nd comment on the mathematical.coffee's answer, the OS I am currently on (at work) is MacOS, but my main machines are running CentOS and Ubuntu at home, so I just assumed my situation applies to all unix based systems.

Comment: Ooh, a challenge.  I expect the answer to be based on the [find command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find).

Comment: Is the change of `master folder/47772/images/2234.jpg` to `2235.jpg` a typo?  (Please say yes!  Or fix it and I can delete this comment.)  Out of curiosity; can there be more than one pure-numeric JPG file in a given images directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-regex` switch to `find` to match `/somefolder/images/numeric.jpg`:

```
find -type f -regex './[^/]+/images/[0-9]+\.jpg$'
```

**Edit**: refinement from @JonathanLeffler: add `-type f` to find so it only finds files (ie don't match a directory called '12345.jpg').

The `./[^/]+/` is for the first folder (if that first folder is always numeric too you can change it to `[0-9]+`).

The `[0-9]+\.jpg$` means a jpg file with file name only being numeric.
You might want to change the `jpg` to `jpe?g` to allow `.jpeg`, but that's up to you.

Then it's a matter of copying these to `xxx_n.jpg`.

```
for f in $(find -type f -regex './[^/]+/images/[0-9]+\.jpg$')
do
    # replace '.jpg' in $f (filename) with '_n.jpg'
    newf=${f/\.jpg/_n\.jpg}
    # see if this new file exists
    if [ ! -f $newf ];
    then
        # if not exists, copy it.
        cp "$f" "$newf"
    fi
done
```

Comment: +1: About the only refinement I see is adding `-type f` to the `find`, just to make sure you only deal with files.

Comment: +1: The OP didn't say which UNIX / Linux or if he can use the GNU findutils, so it is fair to assume he can. You could however add a note that the [standard `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/find.html) does not support the `-regex` option.

Comment: Indeed, updating main question. Never knew there was a difference.

Answer (score 1):

What should be the logic behind the renames in Folder 47772? If we assume you want to rename all the files just consisting of numbers to numbers + _n

With [`mmv`](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/mcp/) you could write it like:

```
mmv "[0-9][0-9]*.jpg" "#1#2#3_n.jpg"
```

Note: `mmv` is for moving; `mcp` is for copying, and so is more appropriate to this question.

Question of Vader:
Well I checked the man page and the problem is that it's a bit strange.
I was  thinking [0-9]*  would match zero or more numbers. I turns out that this assumption was wrong. 
The problem is that I could not tell I want two or more numbers at the start of the name.

So [0-9][0-9]* matches a name starting with at least two numbers (after that it takes all the rest up to the .. Now every [0-9] is one pattern and so I had to make the  to pattern into:
 "#1#2#3_n.jpg" With e.g 1234.jpg I have #1 = 1; #2 = 2,  #3 = 34 So

```
#1#2#3 -> 1234;  _n appends the _n and .jpg the extension
```

However it would rename also files with 12some_other_stuff.jpg sot 12some_other_stuff_n.jpg. It's not ideal but achieves in this context what was intended.

Comment: It's not rename; it is copy to a new name - if the new name does not exist yet.

Comment: Sorry than it is mcp instead of mmv.

Comment: If this is really so simple, then this would be the better solution for this specific case. Could you perhaps elaborate on the syntax a bit?